# TextBox change its position after adding second TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My Xaml code :

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="background.jpg"/>
    </Grid.Background>

    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Welcome to University Portal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="SimSun" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="17" Margin="10,62,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456"  FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="SimSun"><Run Text=" * Select your Domain."/></TextBlock>
    <Button x:Name="teacher_btn" Content="Teacher" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="50" Margin="10,89,0,0"  FontFamily="SimSun" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Click="teacher_btn_Click">
        <Button.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.BorderBrush>
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="student_btn" Content="Student" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Margin="165,89,0,0" Height="50" FontFamily="SimSun" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Click="student_btn_Click">
        <Button.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.BorderBrush>
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>

    <Button x:Name="exit_btn" Content="Exit" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="320,89,0,0" Height="50" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="22" FontFamily="SimSun" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" Click="exit_btn_Click">
        <Button.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.BorderBrush>
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>


    <Grid Name="container" Margin="10,144,0,0" Height="auto" Width="auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

</Grid>
```

I have a `Grid` control and i have to add few `TextBox` Dynamically. It works fine with single `TextBox` but when i add second `TextBox` first one change its position. and after adding `Button` both the `TextBox` have change their position. Here is my code.

```
            TextBlock name_block = new TextBlock();
            name_block.Text = "Enter your ID : ";
            name_block.Margin = new Thickness(5, 8, 0, 0);
            container.Children.Add(name_block);

            TextBox name_box = new TextBox();
            name_box.Width = 200;
            name_box.Height = 25;
            name_box.Margin = new Thickness(150, 5, 1, 1);
            container.Children.Add(name_box);


            TextBlock pass_block = new TextBlock();
            pass_block.Text = "Enter your password : ";
            pass_block.Margin = new Thickness(5, 78, 0, 0);
            container.Children.Add(pass_block);

            PasswordBox pass_box = new PasswordBox();
            pass_box.Width = 200;
            pass_box.Height = 25;
            pass_box.Margin = new Thickness(150, 75, 0, 0);
            container.Children.Add(pass_box);

            Button login_btn = new Button();
            login_btn.Content = "Login";
            login_btn.Height = 25;
            login_btn.Margin = new Thickness(150, 150, 0, 0);
            container.Children.Add(login_btn);

            login_btn.Click += Teacher_Login_btn_Click;
```

attaching the picture of output : [`name_box` should be in the front of `name_block`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoUVR.png)

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to say why the objects move. Obviously though, your `container` is something that lays out its children in a way that adding children causes the existing ones to move. All that said, you should not be manipulating the UI in code-behind anyway. I can't offer anything more specific than to say that you should be declaring the UI in XAML and binding the relevant data properties from a view model (or view models) to the XAML objects.

Comment: How you want to place the controls ? Vertically one after the other ?

Comment: `TextBox` should be placed on the front of `TextBlock`.

Comment: it work fine when there is only one `TextBlock` and one `TextBox` but when i add new `TextBox` it pull first `TextBox`.

Answer (score 1):

Updated Answer:

OK, You need to add 3 elements to your Text block and adjust your Margin on your Password Box.

The width needs to be assigned to your Text blocks, but you may encounter that your default text block behavior sets horizontal alignment may be center, so you need to set that to .Left as well.

Then adjust your Margin in your password box so it doesn't get pushed down another line and you should be good as I have tested with the above updates to confirm.

This is why the below example is much easier to work with, having margins do layout on code behind updates is a huge headache.

---

Improve layout in designer by setting columns and rows and visibility as needed option:

Set your grids with columns and rows and use sizing to handle your layout. Then your margins can keep the gaps as you need them.

Then you can put your container grid with columns and rows and layout your XAML and set the grid to collapsed or hidden (depending on your need). Then on your button click you can change visibility instead of adding the elements programmatically.

Here is an edited version: (top grid doesn't really need the column assigned but to follow flow)

```
<Grid> <!--Notice I added columns and rows to set layout instead of relaying on your margins-->
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="background.jpg" Opacity="75"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="52" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Welcome to University Portal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="SimSun" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="17" Margin="5,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456"  FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="SimSun"><Run Text=" * Select your Domain."/></TextBlock>
        <Button x:Name="teacher_btn" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Content="Teacher" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="50" Margin="10,9,0,0"  FontFamily="SimSun" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Click="teacher_btn_Click">
            <Button.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.BorderBrush>
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="student_btn" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Content="Student" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Margin="165,9,0,0" Height="50" FontFamily="SimSun" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Click="student_btn_Click">
            <Button.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.BorderBrush>
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="exit_btn" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Content="Exit" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="320,9,0,0" Height="50" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="22" FontFamily="SimSun" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" Click="exit_btn_Click">
            <Button.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.BorderBrush>
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <!--Build out the grid and set it to collapsed to give back the space or Hidden if you want to keep the space-->
        <Grid Name="container" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"  Height="auto" Width="auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="lblID" Content="Enter your ID: " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,25,45,4"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblPW" Content="Enter your Password: " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,4,45,25"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtbxUserID" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="200" Height="25" Margin="25,25,25,4"/>
            <PasswordBox x:Name="txtbxPW" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="200" Height="25" Margin="25,4,25,25"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```